# javascript dynamic button click event

Tags: javascript, button

I'm making a dynamic button for each for in a table to delete. I make the button id have the key to the row so I can query it on click to know which one to delete. Since I'm assigning all buttons the same function I need to pass the button that was clicked to the event handler so I can query the id from inside the event handler.

**When hardcoding I'd just pass 'this' to the event handler. How do I do this when making a dynamic button?**

Right now I have:

```
{
var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.type = "button";
btn.id = "btnHistorySelect_" + roundHdr[i].id;              // append the id to the name so we can get it when select button is clicked so we know what round to select as current
btn.value = "Set Current";
btn.onclick = btnHistorySelect;
cell0.appendChild(btn);
}


function btnHistorySelect() {
}
```

The event handler gets called, but I have no idea what button made the click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `this.id` or `event.target.id` attribute to get the id of the button that initiated the event.

```
function btnHistorySelect(event) {

    var id = this.id;

         or
   // var elem = event.target;
   // var id = elem.id

}
```

Because you are assigning the function reference , the **this** inside the function corresponds to the current element is question.

Comment: That's easy enough huh :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
function btnHistorySelect(event) {
   alert(event.target); // Will alert the actual element clicked.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know or assign an id if you are using this

Answer (score 2):

HTML input button element is available inside `btnHistorySelect` function through `this` variable.